# Implement Receipt verification for Apple Store Receipt in C#

Tags: c#, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement a verify receipt for an In App Apple Store purchase receipt.

According to their website it looks like ?!?.

I need to know the structure, can you please help me with a sample of what to encrypt.

Can you please help me?

> To verify the receipt, perform the following steps:
>
> Retrieve the receipt data. On iOS, this is the value of the
>   transaction's transactionReceipt property. On OS X, this is the entire
>   contents of the receipt file inside the application bundle. Encode the
>   receipt data using base64 encoding. Create a JSON object with a single
>   key named receipt-data and the string you created in step 1. Your JSON
>   code should look like this:

```
{
     "receipt-data" : "(receipt bytes here)" 
}
```

Post the JSON object to the App Store using an HTTP POST request. The URL for the store is

> https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt. The response received from
>   the App Store is a JSON object with two keys, status and receipt. It
>   should look something like this:

```
{
     "status" : 0,
     "receipt" : { (receipt here) } 
}
```

If the value of the status key is 0, this is a valid receipt. If the value is anything other than 0,

> this receipt is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize the store receipt into a class like this:

```
public class receipt
{
    public string original_purchase_date_pst { get; set; }
    public string original_transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string original_purchase_date_ms { get; set; }
    public string transaction_id { get; set; }
    public string quantity { get; set; }
    public string product_id { get; set; }
    public string bvrs { get; set; }
    public string purchase_date_ms { get; set; }
    public string purchase_date { get; set; }
    public string original_purchase_date { get; set; }
    public string purchase_date_pst { get; set; }
    public string bid { get; set; }
    public string item_id { get; set; }
}
```

Table 5-1 in the The Store Receipt section of [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide has the field-by-field break down. Hope that helps!

Comment: This is an older version field values (e.g., "bid" is not part of (by that name) the newer receipt format. BUT this is still handy for apps that still send/use older format receipts (which we still have a few untouched ancient ones...) New app probably need the new "unified receipt" schema.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about that past self. As I am now tacking updating the ancient apps in question. It might be worth nothing that the documents describing the available json fields can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/receipt